# What is wrong with my formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been working on an EXCEL formula and am stuck.

```
=If(B10<4, B10*0, If(B10>3 AND B10<8, B10*1, B10*2)))
```

I keep getting an error. Can someone tell me what is wrong with it.

What I am trying to do is say:

- If B10 is Less than 4 Multiply the value of B10 by Zero
- If B10 is Between 4 and 7 Multiply the value of B10 by 1
- Else Multiply the Value of B10 by 2

Comment: seems like `=B10*INT(B10/4)` if the range of `B10` is from 0 to 11

Comment: @slai nice... As long as B10 will not go above 11.  This should take care of that" `=B10*MIN(INT(B10/4),2)`

Answer (score 3):

AND, is `AND(condition1,Conditon2)` not `condition1 AND Condtion2`

```
=If(B10<4, B10*0, If(AND(B10>3, B10<8), B10*1, B10*2))
```

---

That being said you do not need the AND at all:

```
=If(B10<4, B10*0, If(B10<8, B10*1, B10*2)))
```

The second if will fire only if B10 >= 4 so the B10>3 is not needed.

---

And since anything multiplied by `0` is `0` you do not need the B10*0. And since anything multiplie by 1 is itself, you do not need the `*1`

```
=If(B10<4, 0, If(B10<8, B10, B10*2)))
```

- Credit @BruceWayne.

Comment: Assuming OP does want the `B10*0` still in there, instead of just doing `0`, can you think of a practical reason to do so?  I could think they want `B10*1` to force it to become a number, right? Or could that also be pared down to just `B10` without any effects?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have one too many parentheses. should look something like

```
=If(B10<4, B10*0, If(AND(B10>3, B10<8), B10, B10*2)))
```

This formula takes the and statement and places it inside of the second If statement, checking to see if the cell B10 is greater than or equal to 4 and then checking to see if the cell B10 is both less than 8 or greater than 3.

Comment: um...... Isn't that what I answered nearly 12 minutes earlier.  Plus you still have one too many `)`

Comment: I did not see yours, I was already typing mine when yours was submitted. No refresh, Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Can be shortened to `=B10*((B10>=4)+(B10>=8))`

Comment: sorry can;t upvote again, but this is the better answer.

Comment: thanks @ScottCraner. I feel like this version might be even more confusing, but I guess good learning opportunity.